# Prevent duplicate data in using After Insert Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I can detect duplicate records, but when I'm inserting new data it will detect it as a duplicate record even if doesn't already exist.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SDPRawInventory_Dup_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[SDPRawInventory]
AFTER INSERT  
AS 
    DECLARE @Year float, 
            @Month float, 
            @SDPGroup nvarchar(255);

    SELECT 
        @Year = i.InvYear, @Month = i.InvMonth, @SDPGroup = i.SDPGroup 
    FROM inserted i;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SDPRawInventory A
        WHERE A.InvYear = @Year
          AND A.InvMonth = @Month
          AND A.SDPGroup = @SDPGroup) >= 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Duplicate data', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SDPRawInventory
            SELECT * FROM inserted;
    END
```

This is the table

[image: MyTable]

And to clarify there is no primary key nor unique identifier.

Comment: Your trigger has **fundamental** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @marc_s any idea for inserting multiple row while preventing duplicate records? Sorry I'm new in using trigger.

Comment: Why are you using `float` for Year and Month ? Should be just simply `int`

Comment: A simple `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` definitely would be the simplest and most effective way to handle this ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are unable to put a constraint in place, then you need to handle the fact that `Inserted` may have multiple records. And because its an `after insert` trigger, you don't need to do anything if no duplicates are found because the records are already inserted.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SDPRawInventory_Dup_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[SDPRawInventory]
AFTER INSERT  
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.SDPRawInventory S
        INNER JOIN Inserted I ON
            -- Test for a duplicate
            S.InvYear = I.InvYear
            AND S.InvMonth = I.InvMonth
            AND S.SDPGroup = I.SDPGroup
            -- But ensure the duplicate is a *different* record - assumes a unique ID
            AND S.ID <> I.ID
    )
    BEGIN
        THROW 51000, 'Duplicate data.', 1; 
    END;
END;
```

Note the simplified and modern error handling.

EDIT: And if you have no unique key, and no permission to add one, then you need an `instead of` trigger to only insert non-duplicates e.g.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SDPRawInventory_Dup_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[SDPRawInventory]
INSTEAD OF INSERT  
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Reject the entire insert if a single duplicate exists
    -- Note if multiple records are inserted, some of which are duplicates and some of which aren't, they all get rejected
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.SDPRawInventory S
        INNER JOIN Inserted I ON
            -- Test for a duplicate
            A.InvYear = I.InvYear
            AND A.InvMonth = I.InvMonth
            AND A.SDPGroup = I.@SDPGroup
    )
    -- Test that Inserted itself doesn't contain duplicates
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Inserted GROUP BY InvYear, InvMonth, SDPGroup HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    BEGIN
        THROW 51000, 'Duplicate data.', 1; 
    END;

    INSERT INTO dbo.SDPRawInventory (SDP_SKU_DESC, WholeQty, InvYear, InvMonth, SDPGroup, invUOM, LooseQty)
      SELECT SDP_SKU_DESC, WholeQty, InvYear, InvMonth, SDPGroup, invUOM, LooseQty
      FROM Inserted I 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM dbo.SDPRawInventory S
          -- Test for a duplicate
          WHERE S.InvYear = I.InvYear
          AND S.InvMonth = I.InvMonth
          AND S.SDPGroup = I.SDPGroup
      );
END;
```

Note: This doesn't do anything to handle existing duplicates.

Comment: In the existing database I'm working right now, there is not constraint at all so it is hard for me to have unique ID.

Comment: @princenhielcada: what is the current primary key of "SDPRawInventory"?

Comment: @princenhielcada: the picture does not answer my question. But in case there is no primary key, consider to add an autoincrement column "ID" to the table, then the above solution will work.

Comment: @princenhielcada: then introduce one.

Comment: @DaleK Okay, I will test it and review give me a minute. Thanks

Comment: It's working now, but question? Where can I put the Error message when duplicate arise.

Comment: @princenhielcada I've added the error notification as well... just note its all or nothing, so if a single duplicate exists in `Inserted` they all get rejected.

Comment: The `instead of` trigger doesn't check for duplicates _within_ `inserted`, i.e. a user attempts to insert two or more duplicate rows with a single `insert` statement.

Answer (score 3):

This trigger is executed *after* the new records were inserted, so it will at least find the original records in the `SELECT COUNT` statement. Changing `>= 1` into `>= 2` can only partially fix this when inserting is guaranteed to occur one record as a time. Moreover, it will still fail when there were already multiple duplicated of the newly inserted record in the database before the insert.

You need to exclude the latest inserted records from the `COUNT`. But a better idea would probably be to add a `UNIQUE` constraint for preventing duplicates, so no trigger would be necessary.

If adding a constraint is not possible yet, you should initiate a clean-up process to eliminate the existing duplicates beforehand. Everything else is looks pretty flawed to me, since it is unlikely the current approach will ever bring the table into a state with no duplicates.

Comment: The problem is, the existing database is there's no constraint at all. So my solution for duplicate record is using the trigger.

Comment: @princenhielcada: you may think about a process where you clean up the duplicates first and then add the unique constraint.

Comment: I'm thinking of using stored procedure in cleaning duplicate record, but do i need to use trigger after that? how?

Comment: @princenhielcada: when you can delete duplicates beforehand and add a UNIQUE constraint then, you will not need a trigger any more. But deleting duplicates can become tricky in case there are existing foreign key references pointing to the existing records.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the infinite loop. You just have to remove the insertion part from your trigger.

```
ELSE
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO SDPRawInventory
         SELECT * FROM inserted;
    END
```

This should not be in the trigger as trigger is called as part of insertion. you should not write actual insertion in to table in trigger.

Comment: @Popeye the purpose of inserting is if the record is not exists then i will insert it.

Comment: No, Trigger do not actually called instead of insert. Insert will take place if trigger do not throw any error. don't write it explicitly.

Comment: @Popeye any idea for this? I'm new with this kind of situation.